# How can I pass a parameter from a java method to specific xml tag

Tags: java, xml

Can you please share a way to update a value in xml tag, which is passed from a java method

Pass the values from a method to a specific xml tag. Below is a sample code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<company>
  <staff >
      <name>value1</name>
      <location>value2</location>
  </staff>
<company>


public class Populate{


public void populateData (String value1, String value2){

???
}
}
```

Comment: Please add more details like relevant code and expected results.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could invoke an XSLT transformation from the Java application:

```
<xsl:transform 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:param name="newValue"/>
  <xsl:template match="specific-tag">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$newValue"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```